# Entity Framework in-memory database not visible and impossible to add inside of Visual Studio

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to delete the currently existing Entity Framework in-memory database I have for my project.

I can't do that because I don't know where it is and some of the commands which I've found recommended (such ad Database-drop) don't work.

My "Data Sources" window looks like this:

[image]

The project is a .NET 6 Core API.

The objects I have exists in the database, but I don't know how to access that database in anyway other than through the running code which obviously means I am missing something.

Why is the data sources tab disabled from my project?

How can I delete the Entity Framework in-memory database which currently exists and holds garbage objects?

Comment: What kind of Database you use ?

Comment: Entity Framework is ***NOT*** a database! It's a database **access** library - the database is what's being accessed - SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL - whatever you might be using ....

Comment: I failed to mention that an in-memory database is what's in question. I've never had this issue before, this is an unfanthomed side issue on my main goal which is to get a bit warmed up to rapid API development. So, what kind of a databae am I using: I just have the EntityFramework (6.4.4) and EntityFrameworkCore (6.0.3) NuGets and a single DataContext class acessing the database throughy the DataSet property.

Comment: You do not need to delete an in-memory database. It's getting deleted together with the process's allocated memory at process exit.

Answer (score 1):

You can examine the connection string at runtime to determine the location of your database.

eg

```
var constr = yourDbContext.Database.GetConnectionString();
```

The default for Visual Studio is to use [SQL Server Express LocalDb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15), which is isntalled with visual studo.

Comment: I've tried that and investigated if there is some other method, it doesn't work and I've not found another method. I've deleted everything that I could under "C:\Program Files(and program files(x86))\Microsoft SQL Server" and the database still has the old data.
I've tried connecting through the SQL Manager studio using (LocalDB) and (Localdb)\mssqllocaldb, still nothing.